# initializing a multidimensional list with n empty 1D lists in Java

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional List

```
List<List<Integer>> myList;
```

I want it its dimension to be specified at run time, so in the code, I put:

```
myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(n));
```

I was hoping this would initialize `mylist` as a list with n elements each having zero elements but that didn't happen. I only get an empty list. apparently that constructor, "Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity." which is not quite what I want.

I understand that I can loop over `mylist` and `add()`  empty one-dimensional lists, but is there any way of achieving what I want with less codes of code?

Comment: Are you ever planning to add to the nested lists? No, then `Collections.fill` the outer list with `Collections.emptyList()`. Yes, then why should they have an initial capacity of 0?

Comment: As an aside, your call to `synchronizedList()` will only apply to the outer `List`; operations on its elements will still be unsynchronized.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not at the moment, but potentially yes in future. I didn't want to have an initial capacity of zero. I want to add to it as I go along.

Comment: @dimo414 Oh really? so I have to synchronize my iteration over the outer one and then synchronize the inner ones?

Comment: Assuming you want syncronized access to the whole data structure, yes.  More likely however this suggests you don't want a `List<List<Integer>>` at all.

Comment: I think I do. The thread that is filling the data, might add to any number of them, and after the additions are over ( using synchronized), i update my program with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the constructor `ArrayList<T>(int capacity)` does not insert any element in the list, so you are not specifying a size but an initial capacity.

Basically you allow the list to insert up to n elements without the need of internal resizing.

So the outer list is still empty. You can't use `Collections.fill` because you need a different internal `List<Integer>` every time, and `fill` would just set all elements to the same reference. So you are forced to insert them manually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Mind that in any case, since you specified it as a `List<List<Integer>>` (which makes sense), Java wouldn't be able to default initialize anything, since `List<Integer>` in just an interface.

Comment: (Presumably with a capacity of 0.)

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct in thinking that Collections.synchronizedList is not itself a class and merely specifies a way of accessing the underlying list? Will i need to add `Collections.synchronizedList` to `myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());` too?